# How to call angular service method from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm bit new in angular. I've built 'Employee Search' Service module. Here is the code...

```
// Service for employee search
app.service('employeeSearchService', function($http, resourceServerAddress){
    this.empList = [];

    // Method for clearing search employee list
    this.clearEmpList = function(){
        this.empList = [];
    }

    // Method for fetching employee search list
    this.fetchEmpList = function(){
        return this.empList;
    }

    // Method for making employee search
    this.searchEmpList = function(empName){
        var postData = {
                    empName:empName,
                };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: resourceServerAddress,
            data : postData
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('Response Data : '+response);

            if(response['data']['status'] === 'success'){
                console.log('Response received successfully with status=success');

                if(response['data']['data'].length)
                {
                    console.log('matches found for employee search');
                    this.empList = response;
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('no matches found for employee search');
                    this.empList = [];
                }
            }

            if(response['data']['status'] === 'error'){
                console.log('Response received successfully with status=error');
            }

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Error occur at time of processing request');
        });
    }
});
```

Then, I'm using following code in my Controller to fetch data from this Service module.

```
employeeSearchService.searchEmpList(empName);
empSearchResponseList = employeeSearchService.fetchEmpList();
console.log('Search response from server module : '+empSearchResponseList);
```

I can see from my chrome console that, I'm getting data from my AJAX call  with all console message from Service module. But, can't able to catch those data in Controller variable.

I think the way, I'm using 'searchEmpList()' & 'fetchEmpList()' in my controller it's not the right way. But, can't able to find out how to modify that one.

Need Some Guidance -.-

--- Controller Code updated ----

```
// Controller for application Home route
app.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $state, $location, $ionicHistory, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $http, resourceServerAddress, employeeSearchService) {

    console.log('At home controller');

    // Check application session. If it's found not exist redirect user to login page
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("access_token") === "undefined" || window.localStorage.getItem("access_token") === null) {
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableAnimate: true,
            disableBack: true
        });

        console.log('Redirecting user to login page-222');
        $state.go("login");
    }

    $scope.empName               = '';
    $scope.alertMsgBox           = false;
    $scope.alertMsgText          = '';
    $scope.employees             = [];
    $scope.resourceServerAddress = resourceServerAddress;

    var empSearchResponseList=null;

    // Method for employee search
    $scope.searchEmployee = function(form){
        console.log('Employee name entered : '+$scope.empName);
        console.log('Employee name character length : '+$scope.empName.length);

        if($scope.empName.length >= 3 ){

            var postData = {
                    Emp_Name:$scope.empName,
                    access_token:window.localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
                    session_id:window.localStorage.getItem('session_id')
                };

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: resourceServerAddress,
                data : postData
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('Response Data : '+response);

                if(response['data']['status'] === 'success'){
                    console.log('Response received successfully with status=success');

                    if(response['data']['data'].length)
                    {
                        console.log('matches found for employee search');
                        $scope.employees   = response['data']['data'];
                        $scope.alertMsgBox = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log('no matches found for employee search');
                        $scope.alertMsgBox  = true;
                        $scope.employees    = [];
                        $scope.alertMsgText = 'No matches found.';
                    }
                }

                if(response['data']['status'] === 'error'){
                    console.log('Response received successfully with status=error');
                }

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log('Error occur at time of processing request');
            });
        }
    }


    // Method for showing employee profile
    $scope.showEmpProfile = function(empId){
        console.log('HomeCtrl - click on profile image of emp id : '+empId);

        // Redirecting to home page
        $state.go('app.emp-profile', {empId:empId});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` also seems confusing for me.
the `$http` call s done asynchronously so when you call `fetch` it fetches an empty array. 
I would do something like this

```
this.searchEmpList = function(empName){
    var postData = {
                empName:empName,
            };

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: resourceServerAddress,
        data : postData
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Response Data : '+response);

        if(response['data']['status'] === 'success'){
            console.log('Response received successfully with status=success');

            if(response['data']['data'].length)
            {
                console.log('matches found for employee search');
                return response['data']['data'];
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('no matches found for employee search');
                return [];
            }
        }

        if(response['data']['status'] === 'error'){
            console.log('Response received successfully with status=error');
        }

    }, function(response) {
        console.log('Error occur at time of processing request');
    });
}
```

and in the controller

```
employeeSearchService.searchEmpList(empName).then(function(data){
    console.log('data is ready', data);
});
```

Also notice that you have to return the `$http` in order to use `.then()` in the controller ( returns a promise).

Fot a great styleguide for angular [check](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code is working fine. But, can't we store that AJAX response inside a variable in Service itself & fetch that response data by another method. 

I want this, because...  when user will logout from app I need to empty this Search List variable. Else, right now what is happening... if I'm doing any employee search & getting the search list. Then if logout from app & login once again that Search data is visible on the page.

Comment: Can I  see your controller? How do you call `searchEmplist`. On user action ? or does it gets called every time you enter that state ?

Comment: Hey I've updated my post with my Controller code. Right now, whole 'Searching' stuff is going inside the controller only. But, I'm refactoring that code by removing that functionality to a Service. So that, I can handle that user LOGOUT issue, which I've already shared.

Comment: you accidentelly edied my post not yours :P

Comment: ok! :) You have to reload the scope in user logout. but keep in mind that as long as you call `searchEmployee` you will have data in your view. Also another thing that should consider refactor is the `auth check` that also belongs in a service/factory and you can restrict access from the routes with resolve which imo is cleaner!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I'll do that. By the way, what do you mean by "reload the scope". Do you mean by, reloading the page once at the time of Logout?

My Logout code is like this -

    ```$scope.logout = function(){
        console.log('Logout user');

        window.localStorage.clear();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
        $state.go("login");
    };```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95593/discussion-between-koox00-and-mi6crazyheart).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you service works?
I prefer this syntax:

```
  .service('Service', function () {
    var Service = {
        //methods here
    }
    return Service;
  });
```

And you don't need hard work with '**this**'.

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick reply. Yeah, my Service working. Whenever I'm calling 'searchEmpList()' from my Controller AJAX call is happening. I'm just referring this one -  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: I think the problem may be in you ajax request. Try use $q service fro wrapping it

Comment: there is no need to wrap `$http` with `$q`. As per documentation *The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service*

Comment: Don't know a lot about $q service except it's generally used in 'interceptor' for intercept HTTP request/response.